# Load only specific GUIDs as priority in the first load of a file in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I currently have an application where the 3d rvt/svf files are loaded on the browser using the Autodesk Forge Viewer. The files when opened take a while to completely load.

I want to be able to load a file in the viewer in such a way that a select few guids load first or show up on the screen before others. This is needed to improve performance of the viewer for larger files, giving the user something basic to start with and then allowing them to show all the elements in the 3d file, once everything is loaded.

I couldn't find anything related to this in the API reference.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the *dbIDs* of objects you want to load in the `viewer.loadDocumentNode` method. Please see https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only for more details.

Comment: Hi @petr-broz, thanks for that link. As good as that option is, I want to load the whole file eventually. Basically load some dbIds and then have the option to load the rest on demand. Is that something that is possible?

Comment: Ah I see, nice! Yes, you could potentially use the https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/ endpoint to update your guid-to-dbid map.

Comment: I used the ids option to load specific partials on the viewer, but for some reason the GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT isn't being triggered and I see that the progress bar at the bottom right is stuck. Any suggestions on what could be wrong here?

Comment: Hi @petr-broz, could you please have a look at the above.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. It's possible that the geometry loading waits until you load *all* the IDs eventually, and only triggers after that. Have you tried that?

Comment: I haven't tried that but I did try loading only a couple of dbids and it worked just fine. Adding more ids seems to cause this issue.

Comment: So, just to double-check, when loading a model with just a subset of IDs, the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` is triggered as expected, and the progress bar fills up as well, but then, when you try loading additional IDs, the event is not triggered anymore and the progress bar is stuck? That sounds like a bug in the viewer.

Comment: Well, the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` triggers when say I am loading just one ID or two. But when I try to load more, the event doesn't trigger. 

The model does show up with what I believe is all the IDs showing up. 

So in my case, I have to load upwards of a few thousands of IDs and then on the trigger of the `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` do certain other things, which I am unable to do just now.

Comment: Hmm, so a different behavior, but still looking like a bug... Please send this info to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` so we can track it there and report it to our engineering team.

Comment: Sure will do. Can I even add my client as CC to the email so they are also aware of this?

Comment: Sure, please do!